# Git Move Not-Pushed Commit from temp to master branch

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

How do I get from this

```
A -- B -- C [masterbranch, origin/HEAD, origin/master, HEAD]
      \
       D -- E -- F [tempbranch]
```

to this:

```
A -- B -- C -- F [masterbranch ,origin/HEAD, origin/master, HEAD]
   \
    D -- E [tempbranch]
```

I don't want to deal with merging, just have 100% from commit F as the end point of my master-branch.

Comment: Just to clarify: the branch denoted by `masterbranch` in your graphs is actually just `master`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `git cherry-pick` to apply the commit to your master branch. This commands should produce the desired situation:

```
git cherry-pick <id of F>
git checkout tempbranch
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git checkout masterbranch
git push
```

Comment: You also need to push `master` to `origin` at the end.

Comment: @Jubobs: True! Changed this.

Comment: at the first command (git cherry-pick <id of F>) I get conflicts. I do not want to resolve each conflict manually but TAKE EVERYTHING FROM COMMIT F. How do I do it?